# wpf listviewitem returning null when initialized

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

this question seems like it should have a really trivial answer but I can't seem to figure out what is going on in my program.

I have a C# WPF application which is using a `ListView`. The `ListView` has a couple items in it which I added to it by doing this

```
myListView.Items.Add("one");
myListView.Items.Add("two");
```

Now I a trying to access the second `ListViewItem` in the `ListView`.

```
ListViewItem item = myListView.Items[myListView.Items.Count - 1] as ListViewItem;
```

The Error that is occurring is my`ListViewItem item` is null and not retuning a `ListViewItem`.

I've noticed that when I type in the below code my `var item` is returning a string with the value of "two". so I do not see why I am not able to access the object as a `ListViewItem`.

```
var item = clv_TraceGroups.Items[clv_TraceGroups.Items.Count - 1];
```

Comment: When you add strings to the Items collection, it will not magically contain ListViewItems. Why do you want to get a ListViewItem at all, instead of just the item string you've added?

Comment: I want to get the ListViewItem because my ListView has a Item Template with a checkbox, and I want to set the specific ListViewItem's checkbox.IsChecked property to true.

Comment: You should bind the ListView's ItemsSource to a collection of objects with a string and a bool property. In the ItemTemplate, bind the CheckBox to the bool item property. Accessing ListViewItems by the ItemContainerGenerator is a hacky solution for whta should actually be done by data binding to an appropriate view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myListView.Items[myListView.Items.Count - 1]` returns a `string`, i.e. the actual item that you have added to the `Items` collection.

You could get a reference to the `ListViewItem` container for this item using the `ItemContainerGenerator`:

```
ListViewItem item = myListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(myListView.Items.Count - 1) as ListViewItem;
```

Note that this approach won't work if you have many items in the `ListView` and you are trying to get a reference to a container for an item that has been virtalized away for performance reasons though.

You should probably ask yourself why you need a reference to the `ListViewItem` container. There are probably better ways to solve whatever you are tryng to do.

Comment: I Found that when I tried: `myListView.Items.Add("one");
myListView.Items.Add("two"); ListViewItem item = myListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(myListView.Items.Count - 1) as ListViewItem;`  the item var still came up as null. What I have to do is add the item to the ListView then wait for the ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged to changed to Generated, then do what I want to do to the ListBoxItem in that event handler.

Comment: Yes, the container has to be created before you can get a reference to it.